# is there a way to pre-load data from a mongo collection before any other meteor client code runs?

Tags: meteor

I'm having hard time making the Template.rendered code wait for the data to load from a mongo collection:

Template.chart.rendered = function () {

```
    var yelp_data, ndx;

    var template = this;

    template.autorun(function(){
        console.log('autorun is called');
        template.subscribe("yelp", function(){
           yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch();
            ndx = crossfilter(yelp_data);
        });
    });
```

}

I can see, that autorun is being called as expected, but, by the time it finished, yelp_data is still an array of 0.
Is there a way to force meteor wait until the data is loaded into a variable?

Comment: What are you actually trying to render/show/do with the data?

Comment: Its suppose to be a d3 chart, which feeds from crossfilter, which feeds from yelp_data

Comment: I believe the template object has a .subscriptionsReady() function.  Could you do that before setting yelp_data? e.g. if( template.subscriptionsReady() ) { yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch() ... }

Comment: Template.chart.rendered = function () {

        var yelp_data, ndx;
        var template = this;
        console.log('autorun is called');

        template.subscribe("yelp", function(){
        });

        template.autorun(function(){

            if( template.subscriptionsReady() ) {
                yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch();
                ndx = crossfilter(yelp_data);
            }
        }); - still the same issue

Comment: Are you using iron router or flow router?

Comment: neither - just a single page with no routes. here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/6b4f224a74b3c4abe839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on your comments, give this a shot:

- Create a wrapper template, let's call it `chartWrapper`, that wraps your chart.
- Shift your subscription to the chartWrapper template.
- Wrap the `chart` template call inside chartWrapper's Template.subscriptionsReady helper.

Code:

```
<template name="chartWrapper">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{> chart}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

Template.chartWrapper.onCreated( function() {
    var template = this;
    template.subscribe("yelp");
});

Template.chart.onCreated( function() {
    var yelp_data, ndx;
    var template = this;
    yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch();
    ndx = crossfilter(yelp_data);
});
```

I believe this will completely delay your `chart` template until the Yelp data is available.